# Handling error using request module - undefined object

Tags: javascript, json, express

I am trying to get coordinates of locations using Mapbox API via request module in my express app. URL of the request (specific location) is given through html form. It is parsed in the url and the API provides all the information, including coordinates. It looks like this:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    var location = req.body.location;
    var url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + location + ".json?access_token=MY_TOKEN"

    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var coordinates = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates
```

Everything works well if I try any location that an API can find and process. But when I tried inserting some random characters through the form the app crashes, giving the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined". Console.log(data) shows that the features element of data object is an empty array [ ].
I tried handling the error by showing message and redirecting when data is undefied, like this:

```
if (!data.features) {
    req.flash("error", "Location not found, please try again.")
    res.redirect("/")}
```

Im at the beginning of my coding journey and this is my first request so I highly appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What happens when you log the error to the console? I don't see you handling the error anywhere after you have made the request.

Comment: When I log the error after the request is made, there is no error in the console. As I see it is that the request is made with no problems, it is just when I try to assing the value of data.features[0].geometry.coordinates to the variable "location" the app crashes. As I said, data.features is an empty array, but when I try handle the error as shown above it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry was off on my weekend.
If data.features is an empty array it won't fail the test `(!data.features)`.
You could try something like

```
if(Array.isArray(data.features) && data.features.length>0){
 //code here 
}else{
    req.flash("error", "Location not found, please try again.")
    res.redirect("/")
}
```